# How to replace the production website with the development one?

Tags: magento-1.9, best-practice

I've been let down with a developer going AWOL half-way through a project and have had to learn as I go to get our new site sorted.

The current site is : `ourdomain.co.uk/` (not magento)

We have the development site on : `ourdomain.co.uk/beta2`

How do I replace the live site ?

My plan is to backup, delete old site files and replace with files from `/beta2` and use an extension I have for 301 redirects.

Please advise if this is a bad thing to do a better way.

Comment: You want to move the `ourdomain.co.uk/beta2` content to `ourdomain.co.uk/` ?

Comment: Yes without messing anything up

Comment: Hey Ryan, I'm afraid you will have to be more specific. Assuming you got a full setup at "http://ourdomain.co.uk/beta2", independent from "http://ourdomain.co.uk": how about just moving the content of `/beta2` to `/` (or change the webroot, which might be easier, depending on the GUI you use for managing your webspace), remove `/var/session` and `/var/cache` and update `/app/etc/local.xml` with your database details? Whether to use the current "live" database or the one used in `/beta2` depends on what is stored in the database (i.e. has there been another version of your shop online already).

Answer (score 1):

You have two Magento's and you want to replace the `ourdomain.co.uk/` content with `ourdomain.co.uk/beta2` otherwise you want to move the **beta** environement into **live** environement

#### Folder side :

**Schema :**

```
1. ourdomain.co.uk/ 
     server: |___ var/www/html

2. ourdomain.co.uk/beta2 
     server: |___ var/www/html/beta2
```

1. Create folder : `prod_backup` in : `var/www/html` then move all the content of this `var/www/html` inside `prod_backup`, now you will have just `prod_backup` folder in `var/www/html`.
2. Copy the `var/www/html/beta2` content inside `var/www/html/`. (now we have copied the beta2 in live site : `var/www/html/`)
3. Go to `var/www/html/app/code/local.xml` then change the data base credentials from the **beta** to **live** one like this:

   ```
   <default_setup>
       <connection>
           <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
           <username><![CDATA[user_here]]></username>
           <password><![CDATA[password_here]]></password>
           <dbname><![CDATA[database_name_here]]></dbname>
           ...
       </connection>
   </default_setup>
   ```

#### Database side :

1. Do a backup of the livesever **database** then replace it with the beta database.
2. You have to change the base url in the new Database in `core_config_data` table in : `web/secure/base_url` and `web/unsecure/base_url` or via query :

   ```
   update core_config_data set value = 'http://ourdomain.co.uk/' where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
   update core_config_data set value = 'http://ourdomain.co.uk/' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';
   ```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very thorough.

The database I'll just use the new one with magento and forget the old.

In this case I'll just backup the current files in html/ in `prod_backup` as you mention and replace with the `beta2` files.

I may be over thinking this but this is new to me and don't want to be penalised by Google.